# Auto-translate a web page, using Google Translator

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

I'm need to modify my code, in order to automatically translate a web page, even (if it's possible) to hide the button for translation:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'zh-CN', includedLanguages: 'bg', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false, multilanguagePage: true}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

This is what I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Change() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".goog-te-combo").val("bg").get(0).dispatchEvent(document.createEvent("HTMLEvents").initEvent("change", !0, !0))
        }, 3000)
    }
    Change();
</script>
```

This is the error that I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of undefined